# using Spark: binning column1 and find mean of column2 based on column1's bins

Tags: scala, apache-spark, binning

I am learning apache spark and scala language. So some help please. I get 3 columns (**c1**, **c2** and **c3**) from querying cassandra and get it in a dataframe in the scala code..  I have to bin(bin size = 3) (statistics, like in histogram ) **c1** and find mean of **c2** and **c3** in the c1 bins. Are there any pre built functions that I can use to do this instead of traditional for loops and if conditions to achieve this?

Comment: I believe this be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930110/how-to-more-efficiently-calculate-the-averages-for-each-key-in-a-pairwise-k-v

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val modifiedRDD = rdd.map{case(c1, c2, c3) => ((c1), (c2, c3, 1))}
val reducedRDD = modifiedRDD.reduceByKey{case(x, y) => (x._1+y._1, x._2+y._2, x._3+y._3)}

val finalRDD = reducedRDD.map{case((c1), (totalC2, totalC3, count)) => (c1, totalC2/count, totalC3/count)}
```