# Aggregate List of Map in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of map e.g

```
[{'a' : 10,'b': 20}, {'a' : 5,'b': 20} , {'b': 20}  ,{'a' : 0,'b': 20} }
```

I want to get the average of values of a and b. So the expected output is

```
a = (10 + 5 + 0 + 0) /3 = 5 ;
b = 80/4 = 20.
```

How can i do it efficiently using RDD

Comment: The third dictionary does not have an `a`. So shouldn't you divide by three?

Comment: Yes! My bad! Thanks

Comment: it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930110/calculating-the-averages-for-each-key-in-a-pairwise-k-v-rdd-in-spark-with-pyth

Comment: Is there any reason you want to restrict yourself to those methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest might be `map` your rdd element to a format like:

```
init = {'a': {'sum': 0, 'cnt': 0}, 'b': {'sum': 0, 'cnt': 0}}
```

i.e. record the sum and count for each key, and then reduce it.

*Map* function:

```
def map_fun(d, keys=['a', 'b']):
    map_d = {}
    for k in keys:
        if k in d:
            temp = {'sum': d[k], 'cnt': 1}
        else:
            temp = {'sum': 0, 'cnt': 0}
        map_d[k] = temp
    return map_d
```

*Reduce* function:

```
def reduce_fun(a, b, keys=['a', 'b']):
    from collections import defaultdict
    reduce_d = defaultdict(dict)
    for k in keys:
        reduce_d[k]['sum'] = a[k]['sum'] + b[k]['sum']
        reduce_d[k]['cnt'] = a[k]['cnt'] + b[k]['cnt']
    return reduce_d
```

---

```
rdd.map(map_fun).reduce(reduce_fun)
# defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'a': {'sum': 15, 'cnt': 3}, 'b': {'sum': 80, 'cnt': 4}})
```

Calculate the average:

```
d = rdd.map(map_fun).reduce(reduce_fun)
{k: v['sum']/v['cnt'] for k, v in d.items()}
{'a': 5, 'b': 20}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the structure of your data you should be able to use the dataframe api to achieve this calculation. If you need an rdd it is not to hard to get from the dataframe back to an rdd.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([{'a' : 10,'b': 20}, {'a' : 5,'b': 20} , {'b': 20}  ,{'a' : 0,'b': 20}])
```

Dataframe looks like this

```
+----+---+
|   a|  b|
+----+---+
|  10| 20|
|   5| 20|
|null| 20|
|   0| 20|
+----+---+
```

Then it follows simply to calculate averages using the pyspark.sql functions

```
cols = df.columns
df_means = df.agg(*[F.mean(F.col(col)).alias(col+"_mean") for col in cols])
df_means.show()
```

OUTPUT:

```
+------+------+
|a_mean|b_mean|
+------+------+
|   5.0|  20.0|
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` to collect similar keys and their values as `list`.
Then simply aggregate using sum of values divided by number of elements of `list` for each value.

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = [{'a' : 10,'b': 20}, {'a' : 5,'b': 20} , {'b': 20}  ,{'a' : 0,'b': 20}]
y = defaultdict(lambda: [])
[y[k].append(v) for i in x for k,v in i.items() ]

for k,v in y.items():
    print k, "=" ,sum(v)/len(v)

>>> y
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02A43BB0>, {'a': [10, 5, 0], 'b': [20, 20, 20, 20]})
>>> 

>>> 
a = 5
b = 20
```